# geometry median and triangles and circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, median

In $ABC$ triangle let $AF,BE,CD$ medians.Let $\omega _1$,$\omega _2$,$\omega _3,\omega _4,\omega _5,\omega _6$ respectively incircle on $ADG,AGE,...,BDG$
Prove that incircle's center's on an ellipse.